# show and hide context on hover

Tags: jquery, html

I have a lot of divs with the class headline, that hold 2 divs, one with the actual headline and another with a preview text. I only want to show the headline unless you hover over one.

So it looks like this:

```
<div class="headline" data-rating="0.331168021644" onclick="javascript:showArticle(1068);" style="display: none; ">
                        <div class="headline_txt"><h1>‘Rechtse zusterpartij dreigt voor CDA’</h1></div>                     <div class="preview_txt" style="display: none"><p><p>Uit grote onvrede over de ‘linkse’ koers van het CDA zou een deel van de partijleden een afsplitsing beramen. Ze vrezen meer terreinverlies op de momenteel populaire rechtervleugel waarop de VVD en PVV goed gedijen.</p></p></div>                  </div>
```

Atm i try this but the $(this "headline_txt") is wrong, i only don't know how else to acces the object.

```
$("#headline").hover(
        function() {
            $(this "headline_txt").hide();
            $(this "preview_txt").show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this "headline_txt").show();
            $(this "preview_txt").hide();
        }
    );
```

Comment: You've set display: none on the parent divs. How can anyone hover over them if they're not being displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(".headline").hover( //you need to select the class headline, not the id

function() {
    $(this).children(".headline_txt").hide(); //you select the children of the selected .headline
    $(this).children(".preview_txt").show();
}, function() {
    $(this).children(".headline_txt").show();
    $(this).children(".preview_txt").hide();
});
```

Also you need to remove the `display:none` from `.headline` to be able to hover it.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6sQsH/2

Even better you could use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) so you don't repeat code.

```
$(".headline").hover(

function() {
    $(this).children(".headline_txt").toggle();
    $(this).children(".preview_txt").toggle();
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6sQsH/1/

Comment: I personally don't like using `toggle()` in this case because it's possible that it gets out of phase with the `.hover()` event if you ever miss the enter or exit event on the hover.

Answer (score 1):

You create a jQuery object for the hover elements with `$(this)` and then use `.find()` on it to search the children objects for the desired objects to hide/show.  Your parent object is also a class, not an id so you would use `.headline` as the selector for it.

```
$(".headline").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find(".headline_txt").hide();
        $(this).find(".preview_txt").show();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find(".headline_txt").show();
        $(this).find(".preview_txt").hide();
    }
);
```

or slightly more efficient by saving the `$(this)`, you can use this:

```
$(".headline").hover(
    function() {
        var item = $(this);
        item.find(".headline_txt").hide();
        item.find(".preview_txt").show();
    },
    function() {
        var item = $(this);
        item.find(".headline_txt").show();
        item.find(".preview_txt").hide();
    }
);
```